# Conditionally serve static files with express.static function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

```js
app.use(function (req) {
  if (myCondition(req)) {
    express.static(`${__dirname}/REACT_APP_1`);
  } else {
    express.static(`${__dirname}/REACT_APP_2`);
  }
});
```

Trying to serve different builds depending on the condition but it does not seems to be working as expected, I have already searched but nothing seems to be matching my condition, is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`express.static()` returns a middleware function.  That middleware function has to get called while processing a specific route in order to actually do something useful.  You were creating the middleware function, but never actually calling it so you never saw any results.

You could fix that like this:

```
// create our two express.static() middleware handlers
const handler1 = express.static(`${__dirname}/REACT_APP_1`);
const handler2 = express.static(`${__dirname}/REACT_APP_2`);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (myCondition(req)) {
    handler1(req, res, next);
  } else {
    handler2(req, res, next);
  }
});
```

Note, I pulled the creation of the two `express.static()` handlers out of the `app.use()` body because there is no need to create them over and over inside of `app.use()`.  You can create each of them once and then just use the appropriate one according to your conditional by calling it and passing it the `(req, res, next)` arguments for the current request.

Comment: How do I add a `res.sendFile` again? Because it gives "header sent" error when I add after doing this. Adding it as a separate middleware doesn't work too.

Comment: @Abhijit - please write your own question and show your existing code so people can help you.

Comment: Apologies for that. I've made a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67160631/conditionally-serve-two-react-builds-with-node-js